# Background colour change on Click/Touch event not working on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, onclick, touch

When the my menu overlay is brought up on a touch device (tested on iphone and ipad), all the content is displayed e.g. links etc but the background colour is not changing from transparent.

Everything is working correctly on my desktop and others it appears its just touch. Is there an error in my code which is preventing it from working on mobile?

https://codepen.io/whitinggg/pen/bLzxGG

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".menu-btn a").on('click touch', function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');

        if( $(this).hasClass('btn-close') ) {
            $(".navbar").css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
        else if( scroll > 100) {
            $(".navbar").css("background-color", "#CEB400");
        }
    });

    // $('.overlay').on('click', function () {
    //    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
    //    $(".menu-btn a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    // });

    $('.menu a').on('click touch', function () {
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(".menu-btn a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 100) {
            if($('.overlay:visible').length == 0) {
                $(".navbar").css("background-color", "#CEB400");
            }
        } else {
            $(".navbar").css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe jQuery (or jQuery mobile) has a "touch" event. You might be looking for [tap](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/).